# Getting Error - Cannot find name 'angular'

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm starting writing AngularJS app using TypeScript. I have this simple module command:

```
(() => {
    angular
        .module('app', []);
})();
```

When I run `tsc app.ts`, I got this: `app.ts(2,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'angular'.`

Do I need to include something to `app.ts` to make `tsc` understand the `angular`?

Regards,

Comment: Not sure about typescript specific. But in Javascript you need to load the main angular source code.

Comment: Yes, after the `tsc` command, I'll get a .js file to be included into html page as usual.

Comment: I see, maybe you need to tell typescript to treat angular as a global dependency..

Comment: Have a look at this project in typescript and angular - https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/typescript-angular/js/Application.ts

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could simplistically tell the compiler to stop worrying by telling it that "you know all about angular":

```
declare var angular: any;
```

To get all the good tooling and type checking, you need to pull in the [Angular type definition](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) so the compiler knows what is available.

The type definitions are available via NuGet if you are using Visual Studio or various other methods for your favourite IDE.

Comment: Just to add for the non-visual studio folks, take a look at this tool to assist on getting individual type definitions without pulling down the entire repo... https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd (can work like bower/npm via config file)

Comment: I installed the nuget package today (DefinitelyTyped). It's broken.

Comment: bad solution, this removes any typescript type support from the imported *.d.ts file for angular

Comment: @sohnee that is a great assumption. Perhaps the answer could be rewritten so you can't make that assumption.

Comment: That link is broken

Comment: @adam0101 I have replaced the broken like with a link to the type search utility. This will find any available definition and link through to the NPM page for it.

Answer (score 24):

Using AngularJS 1.x and TypeScript 2.x, I solved this issue by running:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/angular
```

and then include the following line on top of the .ts file:

```
import * as angular from "angular";
```

Reference: [The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Answer (score 7):

You need to include angular.t.ds file in the library

Comment: What you mean is `angular.d.ts` . Isn't it? I think there is a typo in the file name in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

For me inside of VisualStudio I used part of Augusto's suggested answer and simply did:

```
npm install --save @types/angular
```

and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

**ATOM**

In `tsconfig.json` file ensure your `"fileGlobs"` points to both:-

1. The TypeScript Definitions you installed with `tsd` &
2. Your `src .ts files`

```js
"filesGlob": [
  "./typings/**/*.ts",
  "./src/client/**/*.ts"
]
```

This will ensure you have tooling for the libraries you have installed *(with `tsd`)* without having to `declare` any variables.  For example, if you `tsd install angularjs --save`, you can work `angular` in your `src/../*.ts files` with all the goody tooling.

Hope this helps.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the following line to my package.json, inside the "devDependencies" section:

```
"@types/angular" : "1.6.17"
```

after that, i just needed to run

```
npm install
```

in order for npm to download all the needed dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the `tsconfig.json` the `filesGlob` points and exposed the typings file:

```
"filesGlob": ["typings.d.ts" ]
```