# Visual Studio Code: Cannot find name angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular App and it works fine, but my debugger is showing me 'Cannot find name angular'.

```
 var table = angular.module('myTable', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

I included the link for angular in my html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I tried also including a link for bower_components also:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

There is a answer about this problem at [Getting Error - Cannot find name 'angular'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915175/getting-error-cannot-find-name-angular)
but I am not able to use it.

Comment: What is the leading/trailing character (`) on your script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue until I ran across this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode/archive/2015/05/22/getting-started-with-angular-and-visual-studio-code.aspx

Basically, here's what you have to do with npm:

```
cd (app path)
npm install -g tsd
tsd init
tsd query angular --action install --save
```

That's it.  When you restart VS Code your problem should be gone.

Note that I didn't use any of the ///reference links as the author suggested in the article, but after the above steps I stopped getting that message about angular not being found and I have already noticed more ng-* options coming through in Intellisense.

Comment: It did not help the problem is still there.

Comment: It solved the problem when the question was asked, in that version of VS Code.

Comment: "tsd query angular --action install --save" now yields "zero results", at least for me. (tsd is deprecated in favor of typings?)

Comment: Both Angular and VS Code were immature and frequently changing when this question and answer were posted.  You shouldn't see this issue any more with Angular 4 and the latest VS Code.  It's probably worth posting a new question here as the odds are practically zero that you've got the same issue as the original poster unless you haven't updated VS Code in over a year and are running pre-release Angular..

Answer (score 7):

Click on the lightbulb that will be next to 'angular' and then choose 'download typings'.