# Angular 4 / Ionic 3 - Creating a Mock Service with Protractor

Tags: angular, typescript, mocking, protractor, ionic3

I'm trying to create a end-to-end test for a sign-up page that I already implemented. This logic creates an HTTP request to my API, but, to make the test independent, I'm trying to create a Mock of my AuthProvider class, the one that's made the HTTP request.

So, following the Proctator documentation, I've this simple example:

```
browser.addMockModule('modName', function() {
  angular.module('modName', []).value('foo', 'bar');
});
```

But, if put this in my test code, I got the following error:

```
e2e/sign-up.e2e-spec.ts (23,9): Cannot find name 'angular'
```

Which makes sense, because the `angular` variable never been defined. My question is: how correctly define it? Why I have to defined? And there is other alternative to create a mock?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and resolved it by following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43709106/6205848) .

package.json under `devDependencies`:

```
"@types/angular": "^1.6.34"
```

spec.ts added the import:

```
import * as angular from "angular";
```